# Convertir base64 a imagen

Tags: vb.net

Mi situación es la siguente.
En mi base de datos tengo una campo `VARCHAR(MAX)` en el cual tengo guardada una cadena en base64 como la siguiente

> image/svg+xml;base64,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

Primero que nada ¿Es posible convertir esta cadena a imagen? digamos que la quiero convertir y guardar en una variable como la siguiente `Dim img As Image` ¿Qué necesito hacer para hacerlo?

De ante mano, gracias.

**Solución:** Encontré la solución en un post de stackoverflow en inglés, del cual dejo el link en los comentarios de la respuesta que publicó Pikoh, para solucionarlo utilicé el paquete https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg/ dejo un pequeño ejemplo por si alguien pasa por lo mismo.

```
Dim base64String As String = "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"

Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes)
Dim svgDocument As SvgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(Of SvgDocument)(ms)
Dim bitmap As Image = svgDocument.Draw()
pbx1.Image = bitmap
```

Comment: Podrias probar lo que se menciona en este enlace https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-Base64-string-as-Image-File-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Esto lo convierte en Byte() pero no en imagen, si uso `PictureBox1.Image = ` No lo convierte ni lo muestra

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el siguiente método para convertir una imagen en base64 a `Image`:

```
Public Function Base64ToImage(ByVal base64String As String) As Image 
    Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)

    Using ms = New MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)
        Dim image As Image = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
        Return image
    End Using
End Function
```

Es posible que debas limpiar la cadena que muestras, ya que `image/svg+xml;base64,` no es parte de la imagen. Por otro lado, la imagen es un svg al parecer, debes tener en cuenta que un `PictureBox` por defecto no es capaz de mostrar un archivo de ese tipo.

Comment: Gracias, de hecho esa es la manera de hacerlo, solo que al ser base64 de un svg .net no lo soporta y tuve que utilizar un paquete de tercero. Lo solucioné gracias a este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100083/converting-a-svg-base64-string-to-image-c-sharp